# Tidy a certain value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

The value for $details['wasprice'] contains the word "was" (ie. was $23.99). I want to remove the word "was" and leave the value just as "$23.99".

Code below:

```
foreach($html->find('div.product-details-contents') as $content) {
    $detail['img'] = $content->find('img.product-details-image',0)->src;
    $detail['title'] = $content->find('span.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $detail['units'] = $content->find('span.unit-size', 0)->plaintext;
    $detail['wasprice'] = $content->find('span.was-price', 0)->plaintext;
    $detail['nowprice'] = $content->find('span.special-price', 0)->plaintext;

$product[] = $detail;

}

print_r($product);
```

I am just wondering how to go about this.

Thank you

Comment: `$detail['wasprice'] = str_replace('was','',$detail['wasprice']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PHP sanitize filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) to remove everything that is non-digit, then put the dollar($) sign back.

```
 $newprice = "$".filter_var($wasprice, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);
```

Using it on your sample code:

```
<?php 
foreach($html->find('div.product-details-contents') as $content) {
  $detail['img'] = $content->find('img.product-details-image',0)->src;
  $detail['title'] = $content->find('span.title', 0)->plaintext;
  $detail['units'] = $content->find('span.unit-size', 0)->plaintext;
  $detail['wasprice'] = "$".filter_var($content->find('span.was-price', 0)->plaintext, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);
  $detail['nowprice'] = $content->find('span.special-price', 0)->plaintext;
  $product[] = $detail;
}
print_r($product);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace()`:

```
$detail['wasprice'] = str_replace('was ', '', $detail['wasprice']);
```

Comment: This makes several assumptions.

Comment: Mine is probably "more universal" and handle weird scenarios, but I agree that @WebnetMobile address the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (substr($detail['wasprice'], 0, 4) === 'was ') {
  $detail['wasprice'] = substr($detail['wasprice'], 4);
} else {
  // ruh-roh
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace anything before the `$` using [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$detail['wasprice'] = preg_replace('/([^$]*)(.*)/', '$2', $detail['wasprice']);
```

Answer (score 0):

A third solution:

```
$detail['wasprice'] = ltrim($detail['wasprice'], " asw");
```